# Deleted products showing when setting related products

Tags: database, products

A while ago I deleted all complex and simple products from my store and to set up custom products for selections. This works ok, but a small number of simple products (not visible individualy) that have been deleted from the products page still show up when I set up related products. Their properties seem to be stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. Is it safe to delete this, or is there another way to get rid of these phantom products?

Comment: I don't see why they'd be there, are you sure you deleted them correctly? If you have their IDs, then go ahead and delete everything related to their entity_id in `catalog_product_entity_XXXX`. Also make sure you clean your cache and all.

Comment: @JulienLachal. You should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Marius I didn't feel like it would be substantial enough to be qualified as an answer, but I can change it if need be.

Comment: @JulienLachal. At least is better than nothing. :). It may not be a full answer but it's a good starting point.